# Feeding input with multiple newlines to read() in C - first character "consumed?"

Tags: c, io, buffer, system-calls

I am trying to read input from STDIN, using the system call read() function.  I am using a dynamically allocated buffer.

I have stripped much of the details from this function - all the error-checking, all the reallocation, etc.  None of that affects the error in question.  Here is the code:

```
int main(void) {
    char *buff;

    long buf_count = 0;
    long buf_capacity = 8192;
    buff = (char *)malloc(buf_capacity);

    long read_count;
    while ((read_count = read(0, buff, (buf_capacity - buf_count))) != 0) {
        buf_count += read_count;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < buf_count; i++)
        putchar(buff[i]);
}
```

The code from `long read_count;` to the end of the while loop is problematic.  When I read in from STDIN, I can input long strings without a problem.  But if I input a string with several newlines in it, I will be given erroneous output.  For example, if I put in the string

```
1
2
3
```

with all of its newlines, then I will receive as output only this.

```
3
```

If I put in the string

```
12345
```

with that extra newline (there are two), then I will get something like this.

```
2345
```

... hence the title.
Neither of these behaviors are what I want, of course.  And I know that the problem is with my use of read(), for if I replace the code that calls read() with something like:

```
int ch;
int i = 0;
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    buff[i++] = ch;
}
buf_count = i;
```

...then the output will be as expected.  If I put in 1 2 3 with newlines on each number, it will give me all of the string with numbers and newlines, exactly as I typed it.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: `read(0, buff, ...` you're always reading into the start of `buff`, even if you had received data before

Comment: `read(0, buff + buf_count, (buf_capacity - buf_count))`. And you probably want the condition to be `>0` to capture the error case.

Comment: Thank you both very much.  I was under the impression that read() would automatically "remember its place" in buff as it read, but I see I have misinterpreted this.  The code works now; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered by Mat and kaylum above.

When using read() in a while loop, reading bytes of input into a buffer one call at a time (for multiple bytes), you have to increment the `char* buf` pointer by how much you have read so far.

`read(0, buff + buf_count, (buf_capacity - buf_count))` is the fixed line of code.